# np.asarray error: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,2) into shape (2)

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, tensorflow, numpy-ndarray

I am experimenting with influence functions to understand blackbox models. I am encountering broadcast error while working with a toy dataset of 2 features and 2 classes. Below, I have summarized the actual error using two lists a1 and a2.

```py
a1 = [array([[-0.00491985,  0.00491965],
        [-0.00334969,  0.00334955],
        [-0.00136081,  0.00136076]], dtype=float32),
 array([-0.00104678,  0.00104674], dtype=float32)]

a2 =
[array([[-0.00334969,  0.00334955],
        [-0.00136081,  0.00136076]], dtype=float32),
 array([-0.00104678,  0.00104674], dtype=float32)]
```

I am trying to convert the above two lists into arrays using np.asarray()

```py
print(np.asarray(a1))
array([array([[-0.00491985,  0.00491965],
       [-0.00334969,  0.00334955],
       [-0.00136081,  0.00136076]], dtype=float32),
       array([-0.00104678,  0.00104674], dtype=float32)], dtype=object)
```

While np.asarray(a1) works fine, np.asarray(a2) throws the following error:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-3060768e9016> in <module>()
----> 1 np.asarray(a2)

/home/devi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    536 
    537     """
--> 538     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    539 
    540 

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,2) into shape (2)
```

I went through many forums describing broadcasting errors but still could not figure out the working style of np.asarray().

When the elements of list are arrays of dimensions (3x2)and (1x2), np.asarray() returns an array of length 2. Whereas, when the elements are of dimensions (2x2) and (1x2), why does it throw an error? instead of returning an array of length 2 as in the previous case.. Any help to understand the same will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to reshape all arrays to have the same number dimentions.

And then you should convert it to a numpy array

```
a2 = [a.reshape(-1, 2) for a in a2]
a2 = np.array(a2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. It works!

Yet, I am still wondering why this reshaping was not needed for a1.

Elements in a1 are of shape (3,2) and (2,).  
Elements in a2 are of shape (2,2) and (2,).

I tried another example where elements were of shape(3,3) and (3,). It threw error as well. It looks like when the dimensions are equal, there is some problem in converting by np.asarray.

Comment: I neither can understand it. Maybe its a bug? Try opening an issue to numpy's github repository